# How to force setVisibility working without any delay?

Tags: android, performance

**Problem :** setVisibility() working with delay. By default `darken_bck_view` with `alpha="0"` and `visibility="gone"`.
I change the `visibility` to `VISIBLE` for `darken_bck_view` through the code and expected that Views behind will not be clickable.

and it works like expected if I wait for half a second after the button click

**But :** When I click on elements behind the `darken_bck_view` (when alpha is started to change) they are still clickable (up to 500 milliseconds).

**Question :** How to force `setVisibility()` method to change the state of `darken_bck_view` right after clicking on the button (without any delays)?

*ContstraintLayout with child elements:*

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
...
<View
    android:id="@+id/darken_bck_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0"
    android:background="@color/colorBlack"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/adView"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="some"
    android:onClick="testClick"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
...
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

*Button click handler in Activity:*

```
public void testClick(View view) {
    darkenBckView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    darkenBckView.animate().alpha(0.6f).setDuration(400);
}
```

Comment: Don't animate view. `darkenBckView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` `darkenBckView.setAlpha(1.0f);`

Comment: Thank you for your comment @HamedNabizadeh. But it doesn't work even without animation

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
mButton.animate().withStartAction(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {   //<-- executed at animation Start
                mButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {   //<-- executed at animation End
                mButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }).alpha(0.6f).setDuration(400).start();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @emandt. setEnabled working perfectly but the question is about setVisibility

Comment: You have Starting and Stopping events, then you can enable/shown or disable/hide what you want at the Start or at the Ending of animation. Isn't that enough?

Comment: The problem is that setVisibility executed with implicit delay. I've tried to apply your answer to make View Visible but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** set listener to `view` with changed `Visibility` State (in my case `darken_bck_view`) right after starting animation. Cause `view` will be clickable only after some time (even if already start to be visible) as I figured out.